# e2e test No specs found angular 2 protractor

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor, e2e-testing

i've got problem with protractor tests, it always throws a message:

```
[10:11:22] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[10:11:22] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Started
No specs found
Finished in 0.001 seconds
[10:11:24] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[10:11:24] I/launcher - firefox #01 passed
http-server stopped.
```

Config file is fine, it reads the e2e file. There is the config file:

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'firefox'
    },
    specs: ['e2e-spec.ts'],
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true
    }
};
```

My e2e file:

```
// app.e2e-spec.ts
import { Registration } from './registrationPage';
import {browser} from "protractor";

describe('e2e-spec.ts', function() {
    let page: Registration;
    let header = 'Welcome!';
    page = new Registration();
    let result = page.getHeader();
        it('should display heading saying Welcome!', () => {
        page.navigateTo().then(function () {
            console.log('Start test 1: automatic redirection of index');
            expect(result).toEqual(header);
        });
    });
});
```

I dont know what to do, it doesn't matter what I put into e2e file, it opens browser, close it and throws all the time same message, I use `npm run e2e`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using suites:

```
/*let suites = {
  e2e: "./*e2e-spec.ts"
};*/

//Bruteforce to find the path

let suites = { 
  e2e2: "../**/*spec.ts" 
};

exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'firefox'
    },
    suites: suites,
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true
    }
};
```

Maybe you should look into Page Object Dessign pattern:

```
let RegistrationPage = require('./registrationPage');

describe('e2e-spec.ts', function() {
    let page = new RegistrationPage();
    let result = page.getHeader();
    let header = 'Welcome!';

    it('should display heading saying Welcome!', () => {
        page.navigateTo().then(function () {
            console.log('Start test 1: automatic redirection of index');
            expect(result).toEqual(header);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Still same message No specs found

Comment: @JędrekMarkowski  Allright, brute force: try this:  `let suites = {
  e2e: "./*spec.ts",
 e2e2: "../*spec.ts",
 e2e2e: "./**/*spec.ts",
 e2e2e2: "../**/*spec.ts"
};`

Comment: It might help us a bit if you post a screenshot of your testing path. So we can figure out where is exactly the correct path.

Comment: It moved into other error "Unexpected token import", i'll look foward issue , thanks:)

Comment: @JędrekMarkowski Great! Now it's finding it but your import methods are not cool :p happy you made it! See you around
* I'm updating the answer *

Answer (score 0):

**It's very simple:**

```
specs: [
'./e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
]
```

That mean it will run all test cases (.e2e-spec.ts) in e2e folder.

[image]